# Are there compilers that optimise floating point operations for accuracy (as opposed to speed)?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, floating-point, floating-accuracy

We know that compilers are getting better and better at optimising our code and make it run faster, but my question are there compilers that can optimise floating point operations to ensure greater accuracy.

For example a basic rule is to perform multiplications before addition, this is because multiplication and division using floating point numbers does not introduce inaccuracies as great as that of addition and subtraction but can increase the magnitude of inaccuracies introduced by addition and subtraction, so it should be done first in many cases.

So a floating point operation like

```
y = x*(a + b); // faster but less accurate
```

Should be changed to

```
y = x*a + x*b; // slower but more accurate
```

Are there any compilers that will optimise for improved floating point accuracy at the expense of speed like I showed above? Or is the main concern of compilers speed with out looking at accuracy of floating point operations?

Thanks

Update: The selected answer, showed a very good example where this type of optimisation would not work, so it wouldn't be possible for the compiler to know before hand what is the more accurate way to evaluate y. Thanks for the counter example.

Comment: How would the compiler know whether you wanted accuracy or speed, other than you choosing between the forms `y = x*(a + b)` and `y = x*a + x*b`?

Comment: There are no universal rules about which order of operations will be "most accurate". It depends on the expected values for x, a and b. It may also depend on your use case. Sometimes, you may *want* floating point arithmetics, rather than the closest possible approximation to real number arithmetics. And then the compilers reordering would give you answers that were further away from the desired values -- it'd *introduce* inaccuracies.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, simple the compiler would provide different optimisation flags :)

Comment: @jalf, Ofcourse there are no universal rules, that even applies to normal optimisation, thats why compilers come with so many options so you can fine tune which optimisations you wish to turn on or off,  I can envisage a compiler that would have these types of FP heuritics as optimisation flags. And the one who really needs not to be close to real numbers can then just not turn on the optimisation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your premise is faulty.  `x*(a + b)`, is (in general) no less accurate than `x*a + x*b`.  In fact, it will often be more accurate, because it performs only two floating point operations (and therefore incurs only two rounding errors), whereas the latter performs three operations.

If you know something about the expected distribution of values for `x`, `a`, and `b` a priori, then you could make an informed decision, but compilers almost never have access to that type of information.

That aside, what if the person writing the program actually *meant* `x*(a+b)` and specifically *wanted* the exactly roundings that are caused by that particular sequence of operations?  This sort of thing is actually pretty common in high-quality numerical algorithms.

Better to do what the programmer wrote, not what you think he might have intended.

**Edit --** An example to illustrate a case where the transformation you suggested results in a catastrophic loss of accuracy: suppose

```
x = 3.1415926535897931
a = 1.0e15
b = -(1.0e15 - 1.0)
```

Then, evaluating in `double` we get:

```
x*(a + b) = 3.1415926535897931
```

but

```
x*a + x*b = 3.0
```

Comment: My premise is not faulty, the first example has two additions and one multiplication while the second has two additions and two multiplications. Multiplications in FP operations introduce no accuracies. That is a fact :) However addition of FP with greatly different magnitudes introduces inaccuracies, so perform the multiplication before after these inaccuracies are introduced increases there magnitude as opposed to doing it before hand.

Comment: Also your point about "better to do what programmer writes, not what you think he might have intended" is true sometimes but not always, that is the whole premise of optimisation. The compiler does something equivalent but faster, however equivalent is not truely 100% equivalent as we know otherwise it would not be faster, so to say do what the programmer says always, means turn off all optimisation. Turning of optimisation is valid in many cases but as a general rule, that can be disputed.

Comment: When talking about optimization, we usually define "equivalent" to mean "produces the exact same result". This transformation does not - hence it's not "equivalent".

Comment: The claim that floating point multiplication never incurs rounding is just blatantly false.

Comment: +1.  The premise is faulty unless you know the expected magnitudes of the variables.  More operations means more truncation or rounding (even with multiplication).  I'm not sure why hhafez claims there are two additions in each example.

Comment: point taken, but I can give a counter example, I guess what you have demonstrated is that there are no golden rules

Comment: Yes, there are cases where (for example), `x*a + x*b` delivers the correctly rounded result, while `x*(a + b)` differs by an ulp in the last place.  That's why I used the phrase "often be more accurate", not "always be more accurate".

Comment: `x*a + x*b` can be done with 2 roundings using FMA, but maybe it's still slower and not more correct than `x*(a+b)`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: FMA does indeed get you two roundings, but it actually makes the transform *more* dangerous in some ways: if a = -b, then `x*(a+b)` and `x*a + x*b` are exactly zero, but `fma(x, a, x*b)` is often not.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers typically "optimize" for accuracy over speed, accuracy defined as exact implementation of the IEEE 754 standard. Whereas integer operations can be reordered in any way that doesn't cause overflow, FP operations need to be performed exactly as the programmer specifies. This may sacrifice numerical accuracy (ordinary C compilers are not equipped to optimize for that) but faithfully implements the what the programmer asked.

A programmer who is sure he hasn't manually optimized for accuracy may enable compiler features like GCC's `-funsafe-math-optimizations` and `-ffinite-math-only` to possibly extract extra speed. But usually there isn't much gain.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Stephen Canon gives some good reasons why this would be a stupid idea, and he's correct; so you won't find a compiler that does this.

If you as the programmer have some knowledge about the ranges of numbers you're manipulating, you can use parentheses, temporary variables and similar constructs to strongly hint the compiler about how you want things done.